# htaccess redirect search specific query strings and remove

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, query-string

I would like to redirect a list of 404 pages to www.domain.com/news/ for SEO reason.

I successfully redirect pages like www.domain.com/news/?p=1234 and www.domain.com/news/?p=111&replytocom=333 with this code:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(p=1234|p=111)($|&) 
RewriteRule ^news/$ domain.com/news/ [L,R=301]
```

But some of these pages have really strange query strings and I don't know how to query them and remove them in htaccess.

```
www.domain.com/news/?p=12345;0;0;0;latestnews
www.domain.com/news/?feed=rss&p=123
www.domain.com/news/?p=123%3B0%3Blatestnews
```

I don't really want to redirect all the url wth /?p= to the /news/ because some of them will redirect to some specific page.

Thanks a lot in advance.

---

OK I came up with a solution for these two

```
www.domain.com/news/?p=12345;0;0;0;latestnews
www.domain.com/news/?p=123%3B0%3Blatestnews
```

I just add p=123;0;0;0latestnews in condition as the code write like ths

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(p=1234|p=111|p=123;0;0;0latestnews)($|&)
```

And they are working!

Still searching a way to deal with

```
www.domain.com/news/?feed=rss&p=123
```

If anyone have any solution please tell me! Thanks a lot!

---

I found the answer for feed=rss&p=123, sorry that I forgot to metion that my site is a wordpress site.

So it seems like the browser is not recognise this page as a 404 or even a page under our server. the page looks like an empty RSS page.
So I decide to disable the RSS since I don't really use it, then do a redirect via PHP.
this is the code in my functions.php

```
function wp_disable_feed() { 
    header('Location: http://www.mysite.com/news/');
    //wp_die( __('Sorry, no feeds available, return to <a href="'. get_bloginfo('url') .'">homepage</a>') );
}
add_action('do_feed', 'wp_disable_feed', 1);
add_action('do_feed_rdf', 'wp_disable_feed', 1);
add_action('do_feed_rss', 'wp_disable_feed', 1);
add_action('do_feed_rss2', 'wp_disable_feed', 1);
add_action('do_feed_atom', 'wp_disable_feed', 1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I came up with a solution for these two

```
www.domain.com/news/?p=12345;0;0;0;latestnews
www.domain.com/news/?p=123%3B0%3Blatestnews
```

I just add p=123;0;0;0latestnews in condition as the code write like ths

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(p=1234|p=111|p=123;0;0;0latestnews)($|&)
```

And they are working!

---

I found the answer for feed=rss&p=123, sorry that I forgot to metion that my site is a wordpress site.

So it seems like the browser is not recognise this page as a 404 or even a page under our server. the page looks like an empty RSS page. So I decide to disable the RSS since I don't really use it, then do a redirect via PHP. this is the code in my functions.php

```
function wp_disable_feed() { 
    header('Location: http://www.mysite.com/news/');
    //wp_die( __('Sorry, no feeds available, return to <a href="'. get_bloginfo('url') .'">homepage</a>') );
}
add_action('do_feed', 'wp_disable_feed', 1);
add_action('do_feed_rdf', 'wp_disable_feed', 1);
add_action('do_feed_rss', 'wp_disable_feed', 1);
add_action('do_feed_rss2', 'wp_disable_feed', 1);
add_action('do_feed_atom', 'wp_disable_feed', 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't try this :

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(p=1234|p=111|p=123;0;0;0latestnews|feed=rss&p=123)
RewriteRule ^news/$ http://domain.com/news/ [R=301]
```

Comment: I tried this, just not working, I also tries (p=111|(feed=rss2&p=123)) to avoid confusing the system but stll no good response. Thanks anyway.